# TeamCity config fails on cleanup of selenium-server.jar

Tags: selenium, teamcity, test-runner

I've setup a TC configuration ready to run Selenium tests once we get a build agent able to run them.

This is the first TC config I've created but it was running until I got TC to run the Selenium test runner. Now it fails when it tries to cleanup the `Selenium-server.jar`.

Can you exclude file types from the cleanup or is there another solution that I'm missing here?

TC build errors;

```
> Problem reported from build script. New build status text is: : {build.status.text}; Swabra cleanup failed
> Error while applying patch: Error while applying patch: Failed to delete: C:\BuildAgent\work\f43641868cf93216\src\django_selenium\selenium-server.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure Swabra cleaner to ignore your selenium-server.jar using path rule:

> -:src\django_selenium\selenium-server.jar

but it looks like there is a problem in selenium tests setup. The error message you posted may be caused by some process (most probably, selenium server) still running after tests are finished. It has locked the library and thats why swabra can't delete it.

Comment: I think you're right. I've stopped seeing it so fixed it as a result of other changes. Still that answers my question so thank you :)